# How to use apply instead of using a loop for a function that takes multi columns as inputs

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I have a data frame, clg_df, that looks like this:

```
prov      wave    clg_id      bar
  11       2005     9         500
```

I have a function that takes the four columns as inputs and operates on another dataframe, test_df.

```
prov      wave   clg_id   st_id   score
  11       2005     10      111     560
```

I want to find the number of students in each prov-wave whose score is higher than the bar defined by the prov-wave-clgid combinaiton.

The final result should looks like this:

```
 prov      wave    clg_id      bar   number
  11       2005     9         500      40
```

I am using a loop to achieve the desired ouputs now. Is it possible to use the apply function?

```
def gen_envy(clg,prov,year,test_df,clg_bar_df):

# select subframe from the clg_bar_df for a given clg prov year combination
condition_1 = clg_bar_df['provid'] == prov
condition_2 = clg_bar_df['wave']   == year
condition_3 = clg_bar_df['clg_id'] == clg

# select the bar associated with the clg prov year 
temp = clg_bar_df.loc[condition_1 & condition_2 & condition_3]
#print(temp)
bar = temp['bar'].values[0]
#print(bar)

# select a temp2 df from the gaokao_bar_df for a given prov year combination
condition_4= gaokao_bar_df['provid']      == prov
condition_5= gaokao_bar_df['wave']        == year

temp2 = gaokao_bar_df.loc[condition_4 & condition_5]

# within the temp2 df, generate a new column with 1 as the score larger than 
the cutoff, 0 smaller than the cutoff
# two conditions need to be satisfied:
# 1. Own score higher than the bar 
# 2. Enrolled to a school with cut off lower than the bar 

condition_6= temp2['score'] > bar
condition_7= temp2['bar'] < bar
x = condition_6 & condition_7
#print(x)

# return the fraction of envy
return x.mean()
```

I use a loop to call the function:

```
for i in range(len(clg_bar_df)):
clg  = clg_bar_df['clg_id'].iloc[i]
prov = clg_bar_df['provid'].iloc[i]
year = clg_bar_df['wave'].iloc[i]
clg_bar_df['envy'].iloc[i] = gen_envy(clg,prov,year,gaokao_bar_df,clg_bar_df)
```

Comment: Can you show us your function?

Comment: I added the function.

Comment: you could use apply with a lambda by `clg_bar_df['envy'] = clg_bar_df.apply(lambda row: gen_envy(row['clg_id'], row['provid'], row['wave'], gaokao_bar_df, clg_bar_df), axis=1)`